# Can features defined in the Linux kernel module be used for kernel code?

Tags: linux, function, kernel, kernel-module

I can use the function of the kernel code on a module or other code using EXPORT_SYMBOL.

Conversely, I would like to use the function of the kernel module using EXPORT_SYMBOL in the kernel code.

Do I have any option for this?

Answer (score 4):

When load the kernel core, the loader should **resolve every symbol**(function) which is used by kernel core.

Because kernel modules are not available when the kernel core is loaded, the kernel core cannot *directly* use symbols, defined in the modules.

However, the kernel core can have a **pointer**, which can be initialized by the module's code when it is loaded. This can be treated as some sort of **registration** procedure:

**foo.h**:

```
// Header used by both kernel core and modules

// Register 'foo' function.
void register_foo(int (*foo)(void));
```

**foo.c**:

```
// compiled as a part of the kernel core
#include <foo.h>

// pointer to the registered function
static int (*foo_pointer)(void) = NULL;

// Implement the function provided by the header.
void register_foo(int (*foo)(void))
{
  foo_pointer = foo;
}
// make registration function available for the module.
EXPORT_SYMBOL(register_foo);

// Calls foo function.
int call_foo(void)
{
  if (foo_pointer)
    return foo_pointer(); // call the registered function by pointer.
  else
    return 0; // in case no function is registered.
}
```

**module.c**:

```
// compiled as a module
#include <foo.h>

// Implement function
int foo(void)
{
  return 1;
}

int __init module_init(void)
{
   // register the function.
   register_foo(&foo);
   // ...
}
```